# Сохранение тела письма html, библиотека imbox

Tags: python, html, email

Читаю письма библиотекой Imbox, получаю тело письма `message.body.html` пытаюсь его забрать -> сохранить в файлик

```
with open(tmp_inbox + '/' + 'tmp_file.html', "wb") as fp:
            fp.write(message.body.html)
```

получаю ошибку **AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'html'** любые модификации строчки `message.body.html` не помогают.
Вот полный код сохранения:

```
for (uid, message) in messages:
    with open(tmp_inbox + '/' + 'tmp_file.html', "wb") as fp:
        fp.write(message.body.html)
```

Может его лучше как JSON сохранять все равно дальше буду парсить ?!

Comment: Попробуйте `message.body['html']`. У Вас ошибка, что Вы пытаетесь получить несуществующий атрибут словаря

Comment: @AndyPavlov, спасибо, так тоже пробывал, другая ошибка **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'**

Comment: "Может его лучше как JSON сохранять все равно дальше буду парсить ?!" И что мешает этому действию?

Comment: @СергейШашко Сергей я еще не гуглил этот вопрос, жду помощи от тех кто знает, типа да лучше сохранить как JSON или нет, или без разницы работайте с файлом txt, html.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать `print(message)`. Посмотрите, что внутри. На pypi (https://pypi.org/project/imbox/) вижу, что там `{'html': ['HTML_BODY']}`. Возможно, что у Вас там список, в который нужно заглянуть, на что намекает новая ошибка